# Counting records created by users across multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, count

SQL newbie and can't quite find an answer that works for me..

I have three tables; lets call them **Users**, **Data1** and **Data2**.

Users can be 'validated' or 'unvalidated'; this makes no difference to whether they can add records to Data1 / Data2.

Not all users will have added records, some will have added to Data1 but not Data2, etc.

What I'd like to do is get an output - for validated users only - along the lines of :

```
Users.ID | Data1 Record Count | Data2 Record Count
001        0                    12
002        40                   1
003        11                   31
004        0                    0
005        101                  0
```

Logically, I know I need to get a list of the 'validated' users, then count, for each of those users the records in each table, but I'm really quite stuck!  Tried reading up on while loops and cursors but I'm struggling to see how I can use them.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: To start with try to find out what is your database and share that info with us. Is it Oracle, MySQL or SQLServer maybe... That is step number one. Then share with us all columns that are important for this questions from all 3 tables. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for responding - it's SQLServer, but the answer below from Gordon seems to suit me just fine!

Comment: Happy to see you have found what you need. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select userid, sum(cnt_1), sum(cnt_2)
from ((select u.userid, 0 as cnt_1, 0 as cnt_2
       from users u
       where validated = 1
      ) union all
      (select data1.userid, 1, 0
       from data1 join
            users u
            using (userid)
       where u.validated = 1
      ) union all
      (select data2.userid, 0, 1
       from data2 u
            using (userid)
       where u.validated = 1
      )
     ) udd
group by userid;
```

Or correlated subqueries is an alternative:

```
select u.userid,
       (select count(*)
        from data1
         where data1.userid = u.userid
       ) as cnt_1,
       (select count(*)
        from data2
         where data2.userid = u.userid
       ) as cnt_1,
from users u
where u.validated = 1;
```

With indexes on `data1(userid)` and `data2(userid)`, this is likely to be the fastest method.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the second method worked just fine!  I just haven't done counts like that before but now it makes total sense!